# Understand the notion of level with apply

Tags: list-manipulation

There is something I don't understand with the notion of levels with apply.

I take this example :

```
Apply[f, {{a, b, c}, {d, e}}, {2}]
```

Mathematica answers me :

```
{{a, b, c}, {d, e}}
```

But for me it should answer me :

```
{f[a],f[b],f[c],f[d],f[e]}
```

As I go to the "2" level in my list which is constituted of thoose numbers.

For example at level 1, I get :

```
{f[a, b, c], f[d, e]}
```

Which I understand because the two elements of level 1 are : `{a, b, c}` and `{d,e}`

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: I think you want `Map` rather than `Apply`.  I am going to mark this question as a duplicate.  Please see the links that will be added at the top of your question.  If you feel these do not answer your question please edit your question to explain this.

Comment: You are `Apply`ing `f` to `a`, `b` etc. See what you get when you do `f @@ a`. It is **not** the same as `f @ a`.